# jscolor library set onchange function for new inputs

Tags: javascript, colors, onchange, picker, jscolor

Hi I`m using jscolor color picker from http://jscolor.com/
I need to create new inputs dynamically, example from site

```
function add() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement('INPUT')
        var picker = new jscolor(input)
        picker.fromHSV(360 / 100 * i, 100, 100)
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input)
    }
}
```

the question is how to set onchange function correct and make jscolor to pass its object with color info.
Now I can set it only for static elements like in exemple

```
<input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">
<p id="rect" style="border:1px solid gray; width:161px; height:100px;">
<script>
function update(jscolor) {
// 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
}
</script>
```

Here is my code it does not work

```
var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.setAttribute("class", "jscolor");
input.setAttribute("onchange", "getColor(this)");
var picker = new jscolor(input);
... //And then I add this input to parent and picker shows
```

but onchange not triggered.

Comment: are you trying to change textfield value and update textfield color ...or the textarea box below that ?

Comment: I need that jscolor pass its color data to function.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and make it wokr using the following code. Hope this helps!

```js
var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
var picker = new jscolor(input, {
   value: "00ff00"
});

input.addEventListener('change', function(e){
   var color = e.target.value; 

   console.log(color);
});
```